# Convering CSV to XLS with out consuming to much memory

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I need to convert a CSV file into a XLSX file with and then upload the XLSX file into a S3 bucket. Currently I am using pandas to convert the CSV file into XLSX.

```
df.to_excel('query_set.xlsx')
```

This works fine for small dataset but fails for large dataset. I am executing my code in a server with 2GB of RAM.

So, how can I convert CSV into XLSX format with out consuming too much memory??

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
with open('BIG.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save('BIG.xlsx')
```

Try using this